# HDF5: Saving a linear array to three dimensional dataset

Tags: c++, arrays, hdf5

I have a small problem saving a linear array from c++ to a three dimensional dataset in a hdf5 file.

The layout in memory looks like this:

```
    |---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----|
    | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
    |---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----|
```

While it is interpreted by the program like this:

```
         x
    |---+---+---| 
    | 0 | 1 | 2 |
z=0 |---+---+---| y
    | 3 | 4 | 5 |     
    |---+---+---|

           x
    |---+----+----|
    | 6 |  7 |  8 |
z=1 |---+----+----|  y
    | 9 | 10 | 11 |
    |---+----+----|
```

Using the following code, this array is saved to a three dimensional dataset in a HDF5-file

```
std::vector<int> buffer;
for(int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
   buffer.push_back(i);
hsize_t dims[3] = {2,3,2};
    hisze_t mem_dim[1] = {12};
hid_t file = H5Fcreate (FILE, H5F_ACC_TRUNC, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);
    hid_t space = H5Screate_simple (3, dims, NULL);
hid_t mem_space = H5Screate_simple(1,mem_dim,NULL);

hid_t dset = H5Dcreate (file, DATASET, H5T_STD_I32LE, space, H5P_DEFAULT,
                       H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);
herr_t status = H5Dwrite (dset, H5T_NATIVE_INT, mem_space, space, H5P_DEFAULT,
                   &buffer[0]);
```

Which results in a layout like this:

```
         x
   |---+---+----|      
   | 0 | 2 |  4 |
z=0|---+---+----| y
   | 6 | 8 | 10 |
   |---+---+----|

         x
   |---+----+----|
   | 1 |  3 |  5 |
z=1|---+----+----|  y
   | 7 | 9  | 11 |
   |---+----+----|
```

I guess this is because the row-major format (z is the fastest changing index). Anyway, is it possible to force hdf5 to write the expected format with only one call of H5DWrite?

I came up with this idea but it does not work. I guess i get the function of the hyperslaps wrong.

```
    ... //Same as above, but before H5DWrite
    hsize_t start[3];
    hsize_t stride[3];
    hsize_t count[3];
    hsize_t block[3];

    //Select two blocks from array. First for z=0, second for z=1
    start[0] = 0;
    stride[0] = 6;
    count[0] = 2;
    block[0] = 6;
    status = H5Sselect_hyperslab (mem_space, H5S_SELECT_SET, start, stride, count,
             block);

    start[0] = 0;
    start[1] = 0;
    start[2] = 0;

    stride[0] = 2;
    stride[1] = 3;
    stride[2] = 1;

    count[0] = 1;
    count[1] = 1;
    count[2] = 2;

    block[0] = 2;
    block[1] = 3;
    block[2] = 1;

    status = H5Sselect_hyperslab (space, H5S_SELECT_SET, start, stride, count,
             block);

    status = H5Dwrite (dset, H5T_NATIVE_INT, mem_space, space, H5P_DEFAULT,
                      &buffer[0]);
```

In my interpretation of H5Sselect_hyperslab the two blocks defined for
the mem_space are mapped to the two blocks of the file space. But
actually the result is the same like described above. Is it possible
to achieve the expected behaviour without reformatting the array and
without calling H5DWrite in a loop?
I

Answer (score 2):

Hyperslabs can only skip cells, not reorder them. So I think you are out of luck.

As you said there are two solutions:

1. Reorder your array in the file. The new dimensions would be:

   ```
   hsize_t dims[3] = {2,2,3};
                      ^ ^ ^
                      z i j
   ```

   Then you can dump the array in a single write.
2. Write your array slab by slab in a loop.

Reordering your array in memory would be a waste of time.

Comment: Ok i already do it by writing the array slap by slap in a loop, but i thought it might be possible with just one call to H5Dwrite. To your btw point. Actually i don't think so because i do one select on the memory space and one on the filespace.